# Possible to memorize what are open before an application exits?

Tags: 10.10, nautilus, gedit, evince, djvu

I have these situations often, especially with the following applications:

1. In Nautilus:

   sometimes, I have opened several
   tabs each of which opened a
   different directory. But Nautilus
   sometimes crashes, perhaps because
   it is running too long or there are
   too many tabs it can handle? I was
   wondering if it is possible to
   memorize what directories are open
   in Nautilus before it exits
   unexpectedly and when I feel this is
   desired, just like what the session
   manager in Firefox does?
2. For document viewers, such as evince
   Document Viewer 2.32.0 and DjVuLibre
   DjView 4.5:

   I was also wondering if it is
   possible to memorize what files are
   open currently, before I have to
   reboot my OS but don't want to lose
   track of what I am now reading?
3. Similar question for gedit.

If there are/will be some solutions,
    are they application-specific, or in
    some cases can they be made
    application independent?

My OS is Ubuntu 10.10

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting to remember all apps when shutting down it is found in the startup applications menu item (last tab if I recall correctly)

Comment: Thanks! In the menu for Applications, the last item is Ubuntu software center. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @Tim in the system-> preferences menu